# final or val function parameter or in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Why has Kotlin removed the `final` or `val` function parameter which is very useful in Java?

```
fun say(val msg: String = "Hello World") {
    msg = "Hello To Me" // would give an error here since msg is val    
                        //or final
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's nice to wish for something and then find out that it is already there, isn't it? :)

Comment: Haha yeah you're right.

Comment: I am using kotlin version 1.3.31 and its not allowing me to take var as a function parameter

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Kotlin function parameters are final. There is no val or final keyword because that's the default (and can't be changed).

Comment: Related 3 year old discussion here: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/function-parameters-are-val-not-var/897

Comment: Yeah I did not even noticed.

Comment: Is it possible though to set a method as final, so that if any class extends from the current class, it won't be able to override this function?

Comment: @androiddeveloper that's the default. Read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods. And while you're at it, read the rest of the manual, which is short, and easy to read.

Comment: @JBNizet Weird thing is that in my case it's not for an abstract class I've created. It allows me to override all functions.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Ask your own question, containing all the relevant code.

Answer (score 11):

After **Kotlin M5.1** support of mutable parameters has been removed. In earlier versions that can be achieved using

```
fun foo(var x: Int) {
  x = 5
}
```

According to Kotlin developers, the main reasons for removing this feature are

1. It was confusing. People tend to think that this means passing a parameter by reference, which we do not support. It is costly at runtime.
2. Another source of confusion is primary constructors: `val` or `var` in a constructor declaration means something different from the same thing in a function declaration. Namely, it creates a property.
3. Also, mutating parameters is not good style, so writing `val` or `var` in front of a parameter in a function, catch block or for-loop is no longer allowed.

**Summary** - All parameter values are `val` now. You have to introduce separate variable for re-initialising. Example:

```
fun say(val msg: String) {
    var tempMsg = msg
    if(yourConditionSatisfy) {
       tempMsg = "Hello To Me"
    }
}
```

Comment: @DanielWilson I am not sure what guidelines you follow. But generally I append temp in front variable name. Or better you can suggest edit.

Answer (score 0):

And another reason is that val and var differ by only one letter.  This can be very confusing.  So for function parameters they removed the option completely.  Thus eliminating the confusion in this one small area (yet keeping it everywhere else--go figure).

Answer (score 0):

This decision was made to avoid [fragile](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fragile_base_class) base class problem. It happens when a small change in base classes (superclasses) makes subclasses malfunction.