# RxRoom Kotlin: Generated Dao - error: local variable users is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, rx-kotlin

I'm using RxRoom with Kotlin. In my Dao class 
If I use this:

`@Insert
    fun insertPaymentRef(paymentRef: PaymentRef): Single<Long>`

Or this:

```
@Insert
fun insertPaymentRef(paymentRef: PaymentRef): Completable
```

the generated `Dao` class throws this error

> error: local variable paymentRef is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

A sneek peak in the generated class is this:

```
public Single<Long> insertPaymentRef(PaymentRef paymentRef) {
return Single.fromCallable(new Callable<Long>() {
  @Override
  public Long call() throws Exception {
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      long _result = __insertionAdapterOfPaymentRef.insertAndReturnId(paymentRef);
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
      return _result;
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }
});
```

}

The only time I don't get this error is if I only make my `insert` call like this:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertPaymentRef(paymentRef: PaymentRef)
```

How do I make the `INSERT` call work in RxRoom: I've included RxRoom dependency and it works because if I try doing `GET` calls like this

```
@Query(PaymentRefDbConstants.QUERY_PAYMENT_REF)
fun getPaymentRef(): Single<PaymentRef>
```

It works

Comment: Just came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40563463/5015207) on final function parameters for Kotlin - if this is true then you've just encountered yet another Kotlin bug

Comment: The error says that there is a problem with variable `users` if I understand properly. Where is that variable? Can't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: It's actually paymentRef, it happened in the UsersDao also. I'm making that edit now. Thanks