# Does function parameter behaves like a val type of variable in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, parameters

I was creating a function and I tried to increase the value of the parameter which was declared as Integer. But it said that the value of that parameter can not be reassigned. I am a beginner so if I am missing some concept please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Kotlin function parameters can't be changed.

(However, if they refer to mutable objects, then those objects can change.  For example, if you declared `fun a(b: List<String>)`, then you could add another String to the List; but you couldn't set `b` to refer to a different List.)

This is different from Java, where parameters are variable (unless specified as `final`).

This behaviour was [announced](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/02/kotlin-m5-1/) in Kotlin milestone M5.1, where it was explained as avoiding confusion (especially in constructors), and promoting good style.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40563463/10134209) answer.